# XPlot offline usage

Tags: c#, plot, charts, offline

Right now, if I use this code:

```cs
var chart = Chart.Plot(new[]
{
    new Graph.Scatter()
    {
          x = data.Select(o => o.X),
          y = data.Select(o => o.Y),
          name = "Loss",
          mode = "lines"
     }
});

chart.WithXTitle("Xs");
chart.WithYTitle("Ys");
chart.WithTitle("Chart title");

File.WriteAllText("C:\\Users\\picolino\\Documents\\chart.html", chart.GetHtml());
```

It produced one single html-file with direct reference to `ploty-latest.min.js` through web:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
```

So can I use XPlot library to export interactive (html+js) or at least static (image) chart for offline-usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a feature request for this on the github page of the libary here: https://github.com/fslaborg/XPlot/issues/43

If you want to save it as an image or pdf there are libaries that convert html to those file formats. However this will remove the dynamic features of the plot.

Another solution would be to get the javascript on your local machine:

You can download the `plotly-latest.min.js` file to the local output folder and replace this:
`<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`
with this:
`<script src="/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>`

You can replace it by opening the file in c# and programmatically do a string replace.
However this means you won't get the latest version and bug fixes for those graphs

Comment: Thank you, Joost K, for your response. But I need to know, do I have possibility to do such export more easy way, preferly using only XPlot tooling. Maybe not interactive export, but just static (image).

Comment: I updated my answer, it seems like there isn't support for that within XPlot

Comment: Definately answered question. Appreciate it. Thank you, @Joost K.